# what software can help me to unwar a war file and get the java source code within it?

Tags: java, war

what software can help me to unwar a war file and get the java source code within it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like http://www.rarlab.com/ WinRar for my XP.  You can even search the war for certain class names, files containing certain text, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use a normal zip utility like 7zip to open the war file and extract the content and use jd-gui to decompile the classes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programaticly, do the following:

Use java.util.zip.ZipInputStream to read the war file. See [Sun Compression](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/)

Once the file is "unzipped". Write a class that will browse the directory tree of the unzipped archive.

Then use a java.io.FilenameFilter that only returns .java files. File.listFiles, 
See [List Files](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/course/2004/oop/resources/shareDoc/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29)